# Placing of Apostrophes

Tags: apostrophe

Which of these would be correctly written - 
*Writing my friend’s names* or *writing my friends’ names*?

Where the intended meaning is that I have more than one friend and I’m writing their names in a list.

Comment: ***my friends' names*** refers to the names (one or several each) of multiple friends, but ***my friend’s names*** refers to the (multiple) names of ***one*** friend

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use *names* (plural), so let's put that behind us.

Using *friend's* is not correct, because it indicates one friend. The plural of *friend* is *friends*, and the possessive of *friends* is *friends'*.

The correct phrase for > 1 friend, each who have one or more names is:

> friends' names

Comment: But it's possible for a single friend to have more than one name.

Comment: All my single friends go by their maiden names. XD

Comment: Well, I am single, and I have more than one name.  The one I use here, the one my real-life friends call me, what the government thinks my name is (which is not something I use or will respond to except when dealing with the government), the name that appears on my bank accounts & credit cards...